# Check if a video exists on Youtube (api v3)

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When user inputs a youtube url, I want to make sure if the video exists on youtube so that I can embed and display it using jquery. Every other answers I found didnt worked for me, since they were for the older api versions.

How do I check in it API v3 (preferably without using OAuth)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) pass it part = "id" and the id of the video.

example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id=b_bJQgZdjzo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

a valid one will return

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/s9adeWYKEr1MaBoLwoe5XKS3VnY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/yMdFb3bBbXC_5kG0I6NON02yC0U\"",
   "id": "b_bJQgZdjzo"
  }
 ]
}
```

an invalid one will return

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"mPrpS7Nrk6Ggi_P7VJ8-KsEOiIw/fseqvds4o9r_b2TtUNVFskKrE9s\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

videos.list is a public call so you just need a public api key not Oauth.

Comment: and how do i get the api key?

Comment: Create a project on Google developers console https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0  I have a tutorial that walks you though how to create it. http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/ but I need to update the pictures they changed the UI

Comment: thanks, it was really helpful. So do I create a server key or broswer key?

Comment: Depends on where you are using it really.  Being that you are using it from jquery its probably best for security reasons to create a browser key then add your web address to it.   But it can be tricky to get it to work you may have to play with what URL you have to put in * .example.com/ * normally works. but if you are testing from local host you will have to add that as well.

Comment: It worked with both servery key and browser key. Like you said, I'll use the browser key. This was really helpful. Thank you so much.